# How can I get all triples contained in a SPARUL INSERT Data statement without writing my own parser?

Tags: java, sparql, ontology

I'm searching for a method to extract all triples that are contained in a SPARQL Update `INSERT DATA` string. Of course it would be possible to write an own parser for `INSERT DATA` statements but if possible, I want to avoid that.

For example, there could be an update that looks similar to this:

```
Insert Data {
<http://test.com/example/book1> <http://test.com/example/hasTitle> <http://test.com/TestTitle1> . 
<http://test.com/example/book2> <http://test.com/example/hasTitle> <http://test.com/example/TestTitle2> .
}
```

Is there a library that delivers subject, predicate, and object for those two triples? My overall goal is to have an `ArrayList` that contains the triples. In the best case, the method should also work with prefixes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apache Jena and RDF4J both can parse SPARQL 1.1 Update and allow for getting the triples.

Comment: Notice that he asks about SPARUL, not SPARQL. That's a Virtuoso-specific language iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the code do the work.  Execute the request on an empty dataset and then inspect the result.